# Leaflet get id from geojson and bind it to popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, leaflet

```html
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', undefined, options);
    map.setView([56.413300, 8.869450], 16)
    var markerpositions;
    map.addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9'));
   // L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);
   var geocoder = L.control.geocoder('search-MKZrG6M').addTo(map);
    L.marker([56.41083875205333, 8.864636421203615], {icon: HydrantIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Hydrant  1");
    L.marker([56.41069629842804, 8.868584632873537], {icon: HydrantIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Hydrant  2");
    L.marker([56.40941419180167, 8.866181373596193], {icon: HydrantIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Hydrant  3");
    var data = <?php echo JSON_encode($geojson); ?>;
    var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
function requestGeoJson(){
    fetch('https://laerkeholt.dk/admin/get-features')
      .then(function(response){ return response.json() })
      .then(function(json){
         geoJsonLayer.clearLayers().addData(json).bindPopup('ID: + IDHERE');
         var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
         var url = "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/vandingsmaskine/with/key/";
          http.open("POST", url, true);
          http.send(JSON.stringify({"value1": "ID 1"}));
          var hydrat1 = [56.41083875205333, 8.864636421203615];
          var hydrat2 = [56.41069629842804, 8.868584632873537];
          var hydrat3 = [56.40941419180167, 8.866181373596193];
          var test = L.latLng(json).distanceTo(hydrat1);
          <?php echo $test ?>
    
         setTimeout(requestGeoJson, 5000);
      });
};
requestGeoJson();
```

So basically I want to have it so geoJsonLayer binds a popup with the id it got for the response JSON so each marker would be assigned its specific id from the response JSON. 
I have tried todo json.properties.id to try and get the ID

Comment: Check out the `pointToLayer` function on the `L.geoJson` object. That's where you can brew your own `L.marker` for each point in the geoJSON file and add a suitable popup.

Comment: What ?? don't really wouldnt i use some kind of eachfeature? @peeebeee

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @peeebeee Asking how i would use a id from the geojson from the url in the post

Comment: getting the id parameter from this geojson https://laerkeholt.dk/admin/get-features and binding it to a popup on each of the markers so instead of both of them saying ID 1 there would say there specific id from the geojson features paremeter @peeebeee

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `pointToLayer` or `onEachFeature` for this.

When you instantiate the geoJSON layer, use this:

`var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(false, {onEachFeature: addMyPopup}).addTo(map);`

```
// Initialise the three reference points
var hydrat1 = L.latLng(<..>, <..>);
var hydrat2 = L.latLng(<..>, <..>);
var hydrat3 = L.latLng(<..>, <..>);

// This gets called for every point in the GeoJSON
function addMyPopup ( feature, layer) {
if ((layer.getLatLng().distanceTo(hydrat1) < 5)
  ||(layer.getLatLng().distanceTo(hydrat2) < 5)
  ||(layer.getLatLng().distanceTo(hydrat3) < 5)) {
    // Do something
  }
  layer.bindPopup("My ID is: " + feature.properties.id);
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.                                                                     var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson({onEachFeature: addMyPopup}).addTo(map);                         https://stackoverflow.com/users/3574481/peeebeee

Comment: I would also need to remove .bindPopup from the adddata right

Comment: Ah, the input object isn't quite as optional as the spec suggests. Edited.

Comment: Yes, that bindPopup isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: Still getting Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.
    at Jt (leaflet-src.js:8773)
    at e.addData (leaflet-src.js:8673)
    at e.initialize (leaflet-src.js:8648)
    at new e (leaflet-src.js:301)
    at Object.oi (leaflet-src.js:8974) while using var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson({}, {onEachFeature: addMyPopup}).addTo(map);

Comment: Sorry, lack of testing here. A constant `false` should do it (edited)

Comment: Thanks, One last question how would I get both coordinates long and latitude from https://laerkeholt.dk/admin/get-features

Comment: something like feature.geometry.latitude or?

Comment: trying to check all data from the geojson with a distanceto

Comment: calling it from inside the requestGeoJson function so cant use feature

Comment: You can use `feature.geometry.coordinates` which is an array of Lng and Lat. Or since `layer` is a `L.marker`, it might be easier to use `layer.getLatLng()`.

Comment: ReferenceError: feature is not defined cant figure out how to do this with oneachfeature https://pastebin.com/Edu3mThD @peeebeee

Comment: You appear to have completely misunderstood what `onEachFeature` does. It allows you to specify a function that gets called by the L.geoJson parser for every feature in the GeoJSON data. In that function, you can (for example) add a popup to the marker as my answer shows. You've tried to do something completely different with it. Have a read of the example at https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/

Comment: Oh but then how would I do I want to in the Requestgeojson check if any of the markers are within 5 meters range of any of the Hydrat Points if any of the Markers are within 5 meters range I will get the id for the specific one that is in range and send a webhook(i know how to do the webhook) @peeebeee

Comment: Your `onEachFeature()` function gets called for each marker. You can do whatever processing you want in that function - including checking distance from other things, calling webhooks, etc.

Comment: Yes but i cant call feature.properties.id for each since its in the requestgrojson function @peeebeee

Comment: onEachFeature is called by L.geoJson.addData for each feature. So you can access feature.properties.id

Comment: but how would the if statement look foreach im thinking something like if(json.distanceto(hydrat1 || hydrat2 || hydrat3) = < 5meters                                                                   So like the distance from the geojson points equels less than 5 meters to any of the hydrats @peeebeee